# Why can't I add a reference to a .NET Core 2.0 Library in my UWP v6.0.1 Project?

Tags: .net, uwp, .net-core, .net-native

I have two .NET Core 2.0 projects and a Universal Windows Platform version v6.0.1 project (main) in my solution (both targets set to Build 16299). When any of the two .NET Core 2.0 projects, I get an error message "Unable to add a reference to project "xx". It would be nice if it told me why.

As a test, I added a new .NET Standard 2.0 library and I was able to reference it. From my limited understanding, .Net Standard 2.0 is compatible with .Net Core 2.0 which is the latest, so shouldn't .NET Core 2.0 also be compatible with UWP 6.0.1?  When I look at the chart comparing .NET standards, it clearly states that .NET Standard 2.0 is and .NET Core 2.0 are compatible.

[.Net Standard Versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blmop.png)

If all of this isn't amazingly confounding, the UWP project has the Microsoft .NETCore packages which list .NET Core 2.0:

[image: UWP v6.0.1 Nuget Package Description]
[image]

Also, although not shown, the UWP package has a .NETCore, Version 5.0 dependency!  I was under the impression .NET Core is only at version 2.0:

[image]

What's going on here?  Some clarification would be great.

**ASIDE:**  Microsoft appears to be an incoherent organization as exhibited with this mindbogglingly confusing .NET architecture along with its scattered and disorganized documentation. It seems as if all the different departments are duplicating efforts with no higher level guidance.  Perhaps, they need a .NET Czar.

Comment: Once you really understand the project types, such won’t be questions any more, https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Core implements .NET Standard but it may have some APIs that are not available anywhere else. What you're saying is like saying "UWP implements .NET Standard so I could use UWP APIs in every .NET Standard project" and that's not true.

.NET Standard is just a subset of APIs available on all the .NET platforms. It's a replacement for PCLs. You can use .NET Standard library in every .NET app/library that uses .NET that implements that certain version of .NET Standard.

PS: Yeah, the relations between .NET Standard and others is kinda confusing. Also took me some time to understand it.

Comment: Fair enough, but if you look at the two packages, they both reference .NetCore 2.0.  Also, what's with .NetCore 5.0?

Comment: AFAIK UWP is build on top of (probably some special version of) .NET Core. Not sure about the versioning but I've seen the 5.0 version only with UWP so I believe that it's the UWP version of .NET Core.

Comment: Btw, UWP run .Net native which throws another wrench in the vortex of confusion.

Comment: .NET Native is a compilation technology and a small runtime that makes the app smaller, faster and having smaller memory footprint. The name is kinda misleading in my opinion..

Comment: And they're working on enabling it even for classic .NET Core apps AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the matrix on this page - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

In your example, if you want to consume a .NET Standard 2.0 library from a UWP project, the UWP project must have min target set as 16299

[image]

Similarly, netcore 2.0 can consume netstandard 2.0

Provide information on exactly which package you are tying to install and into which project. Usually the output window tells you exactly why package installation failed.

```
Restoring packages for C:\Users\karann\Source\Repos\UWPWeatherAppKRN\UWPWeatherAppKRN\UWPWeatherAppKRN.csproj...
NU1202: Package netstandard2_lib 1.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586). Package netstandard2_lib 1.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
NU1202: Package netstandard2_lib 1.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-arm. Package netstandard2_lib 1.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
NU1202: Package netstandard2_lib 1.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-arm-aot. Package netstandard2_lib 1.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
NU1202: Package netstandard2_lib 1.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-x64. Package netstandard2_lib 1.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
NU1202: Package netstandard2_lib 1.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-x64-aot. Package netstandard2_lib 1.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
NU1202: Package netstandard2_lib 1.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-x86. Package netstandard2_lib 1.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
NU1202: Package netstandard2_lib 1.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-x86-aot. Package netstandard2_lib 1.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'UWPWeatherAppKRN'.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:01.1049694
```

Search for NU1202 and you'll get this page [Errors and warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings#nu1202)